# Will EXECVP system call supports IO redirections

Tags: c, execvp

Will EXECVP system call supports IO redirections

That means is this give desired output

```
char *args[]={"cat","A.txt","B.txt",">","C.txt",NULL};
execvp(args[0],args);
```

I mean will the data in A.txt and B.txt goes to C.txt

If no why ?

**UPD** : I have asked two doubts in comment please clarify it

Comment: No.  Because redirection is a feature of the *SHELL*; execvp merely launches a *PROCESS*.

Comment: You can invoke the shell to do redirections: `char *args[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cat A.txt B.txt > C.txt", NULL }; execv(args[0], args);`

Comment: @paulsm4, minor nitpick: `execvp` doesn't launch a new process, but replaces the current process image. Otherwise, yes, you are right.

Comment: execvp will use the arguments `cat`, `A.txt`, `B.txt`, `>`, and `C.txt`. The > will not be treated as a redirection. But execvp will support redirections in the sense that the process retains its open file descriptors (unless they are marked close on exec), so you can redirect those at will and the redirections will be retained.

Comment: @HAL9000: I just wanted to explain to the user that "exec()" and friends have *NOTHING* directly to do with "I/O redirection", without getting too "overcomplicated".  I actually googled for a tutorial, but didn't find anything I liked. 
 Your response below is *EXCELLENT*.

Comment: @paulsm4 :  execvp merely launches a PROCESS . Once can you elaborate this line

Comment: @sanathkumar, the important part of @paulsm4s comment was "Redirection is a feature of the SHELL", "execvp merely..." just means that `execvp` just passes arguments along without analyzing them. "...launches a PROCESS" is technically wrong, see my other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically not an answer to your question, that has been answered in the comments. But an explanation to how you can do redirection with `execvp`

When starting a new program with `execvp`, it will inherit the current file descriptor. So if you setup file descriptor 1 (which is used for stdout)
to be redirected to "C.txt" before calling `execvp`, the new program will
write to "C.txt":

```
// Open "C.txt" for writing, creating it if it doesn't exist, or
// clearing its content if it does exist.
// `mode` should be set as appropriate 
//
int fd = creat("C.txt", mode);
if (fd == -1)
{
   // Swap out error handling to suit your needs
   perror("open failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// We want new process to have "C.txt" on file descriptor 1
if (dup2(fd, 1) == -1)
{
   perror("dup failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


// "C.txt" is now writable on file descriptor 1, so we don't need the
// old one. Actually, the old one could confuse the new executable.
close(fd);


// We can now execute new program. It will inherit current open 
// file descriptors and it will see "C.txt" on file descriptor 1
char *args[]={"cat","A.txt","B.txt",NULL};
execvp(args[0],args);

// If we reach this point, `execvp` failed.
perror("execvp failed");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: @sanath kumar: please "upvote" and "accept" this reply, if you find it helpful.  Please post back if you have additional questions.

Comment: What I have left out in the example above, is the `fork` part. Normally when the `exec` family of functions are used, there is a `fork` involved. The `creat` (or `open`) can be called before `fork` for better error handling. `dup2` must naturally come after `fork` in the child process, otherwise we would redirect stdout in the parent process.

Comment: it wasn't really necessary to get into [fork()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), which enables "concurrency".  The important parts were [dup2()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) and [close()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html).  Which are the standard C library calls used to actually implement I/O redirection (e.g. ">").  When the user types ">", the shell (e.g. /bin/sh, /bin/bash, etc. etc) execute "dup2()" and "close()" to implement the redirection.  Again - good job!  I hope it helps the OP.

Comment: @HAL9000 : will execvp will exit if it executed successfully ? I mean I didnot got this line : // If we reach this point, `execvp` failed.

Comment: @sanathkumar, `execvp` wont "exit" by itself, but the new program might. What happens when (successfully) calling `execvp`, is that the program in the current process gets "replaced" by the new program. The new program takes over a lot of stuff from the old program, including file descriptors, process id and permissions, but not program code and data. The old program gets "deleted" from memory. It does not "exit", that would mean returning a value to a waiting process. Any process waiting for the old program to exit, will keep waiting for the new program to exit, without knowing the difference

Comment: @sanathkumar, even if `execvp` doesn' actally call `exit`, as a simplified mental model (even if technically wrong) it is not a bad one. You can think of `execvp` doing this: `void *prog = load_prog(args[0]); int retval = call(prog, "main", args); exit(retval);`. Naturally this is very simplified. On a real OS there is a lot of kernel functions involved, including cleaning up unneeded program and data memory.